# Capybara's existing test + using Selenium to run the tests against a remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, selenium, rspec, capybara

first of all, excuse my bad English, and execuse my lake of knowledge, am totally new to web development.

I wrote some Tests (Capybara & Rspec), and i am trying to run them against a remote server.
i know that it's possible because i read this in the Capybara documents :

*"Normally Capybara expects to be testing an in-process Rack application, but you can also use it to talk to a web server running anywhere on the internet"*

i've been trying to run the tests against the remote server scince the last 2 days, but no luck.
i even read here in stackoverflow that i should use the following :

```
    Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
    Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.google.com'
```

but i really don't know in which file! it's not written were i should write this, and as i said, am really new to web development.

i even did not find a tutorial for beginners to teach how to set Selenium to take care of running the tests against the remote server rather than locally !.

any help would be really appreciated !

PS:

no, am not trying to click on banners (as some one thought on an IRC channel), i am trying to do this for a job opportunity :)
Thanks.

Comment: i found out that i could write that configuration inside the test it self, if i want to run that specific test on a remote server, or i could write that in the spec_helper if i want this to be the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That configuration would normally go in `spec/spec_helper.rb`.